# Continuing script in selenium when element is not present on a page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findelement

I am trying to get selenium set up to send out messages automatically and have not yet got around to check if the specific listing has already been sent a message. This causes selenium to give a NoSuchElementException because its looking for (By.XPATH, ('//span[contains(text(),"Message")]'))
How can I have it skip these pages where the element doesn't exist?

```
message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ('//span[contains(text(),"Message")]'))
   
message.click()
```

Very small snippet that shows the code where the issue is.

Comment: take decision if `message` is None

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `find_element` you should use `find_elements` here.
`find_elements` returns a list of found matches. So, in case of match (such element exists) it will return non-empty list. It will be interpreted by Python as Boolean `True`. Otherwise, in case of no matches found the returned list is empty, it is interpreted by Python as Boolean `False`.
To perform click you can get the first element in the returned list, as following:

```py
message = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ('//span[contains(text(),"Message")]'))
if message:
    message[0].click()
```